# How can I convert a cubic to a linear equation using logs or other method?

Tags: calculus, statistics, linear-programming, mathematical-modeling

is it possible and if so how, to convert a cubic into a linear equation?

$$Y=-0.152x^3+5.79x^2-86.8x+719$$

Is there anyway, such as using logs, to convert it into a Linear form?

Cheers

Jack

(someone had some similar maths at [How can I convert fifth order polynomial to a linear equation using logs?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/894484/how-can-i-convert-fifth-order-polynomial-to-a-linear-equation-using-log))

(Anyway to work it into excel would be incredible!!! cheers)

Comment: Well, it is basically what is says the post that you linked, but for a polynomial of 3 roots: "rewrite your polynomial as $Y=\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^3\Big(X-x_k\Big)$, where $x_{_{1-3}}$ are its three roots. Then take the logarithm of both sides, and use the fact that the logarithm of a product is the sum of logarithms... What is the problem with that?

Comment: The above translates to $\sum \ln k = \ln1 - \ln3$ and as $\ln1 = 0$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, find the three roots of the polynomial $\;Y=-0.152x^3+5.79x^2-86.8x+719$.

These are $x_1=21.871,\;x_2=8.11057 + 12.2678 i,\;x_3=8.11057 - 12.2678 i$, so we can write the polynomial as

$$Y=\left(X-21.871\right)\left(X-(8.11057\pm 12.2678 i)\right)$$

Now taking $\ln$ on both sides we get

$$\ln(Y)=\ln\left(X-21.871\right)+\ln\left(X-(8.11057 + 12.2678 i)\right)+\ln\left(X-(8.11057 - 12.2678 i)\right)$$

This is your new equation obtained by taking logarithms.

Comment: Provided, of course, that one knows how to make sense of the logarithm of a nonreal number.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, that's a very good point. Didn't think about that.